# If command with user input OS X terminal

Tags: macos, bash, if-statement, terminal

So I'm new to the OS X terminal and I'm trying to figure out how to use the `if` command with the `read` command.

Like this:

```
echo stuff:
read f
if [ "f" == "y"]
then 
echo wassup
else exit
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're asking bash to compare whether the strings `f` and `y` are equivalent. Clearly, they're not. You need to use a variable substitution:

```
if [ "$f" == "y" ]
```

With this, it's asking “is the string consisting of the contents of the variable `f` equivalent to the string `y`?”, which is probably what you were trying to do.

You're also missing an `fi` (`if` backwards), which ends the `if` statement. Together:

```
if [ "$f" == "y" ]
then
    # true branch
else
    # false branch
fi
```

Comment: @SpectrumCreations Also, note that you do not have a space before the closing `]` in your original post; it's required.